# How to use scoped objects on DelegatingHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a `ProductService` that calls an API. When I call GetAsync, it automatically triggers my AuthenticationHandler. But unfortunately, a value that I carry on my variable, it comes null. Can you help me?

I used `services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();`

In other classes, I can get the value, but not in the handler.

Why my scoped `ProductService` is reseted when I activate my DelegatingHandler?

```
public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
       private readonly IProductService _productService;
    
       public AuthenticationHandler (IProductService productService) {
           _productService = productService;
       }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var testing = _productService.GetStoredValue();
        var response = await base.SendAsync(req, cancellationToken);           
       
        return response;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If I've understood correctly, your problem is that the IProductService you inject is reseted each time you enter in your AuthenticationHandler right?
In this case, you probably need to add your ProductService as singleton for the dependency injection.
Try with `services.AddSingleton <IProductService, ProductService>`

Comment: I can't use it as a singleton. I want to keep the value only in the request.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you'll need to IHttpContextAccessor to resolve the issue and get the instance you want.

You need to inject the IHttpContextAccessor interface into your application and  resolve the scoped service and get the instance you want.

Like below:

```
   public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
   
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public AuthenticationHandler(  IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
    
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var httpConext = _accessor.HttpContext;

            // retrieve the service from the Request DI Scope
            var service = _accessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IProductService>();


            var testing = _productService.GetStoredValue();
            var response = await base.SendAsync(req, cancellationToken);

            return response;
        }
    }
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/#an-example-of-unexpected-for-me-scoped-service-behaviour-in-ihttpclientfactory).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for you answer, but I've tried this before and the HttpContext is always null. It comes from rabbit mq, not by controller. I read the article, but It is not working yet.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you use this DelegatingHandler with rabbit mq? I mean how rabbit mq give you the httpcontext. Could you please give me some codes?

Comment: Actually, I don't have the httpcontext. Get it? My application calls a api, but it's not called by a my API Do you understand me?